# Is there any alternative way which i can use instead of "<" in CASE Statement? Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any alternative way  which I can use instead of "<" in CASE Statement?

that is my table:

```
create table table (id, numbrr) as
 select   1, 450  from dual union all
select   2, 120 from dual union all
select   33, 130 from dual ;
```

that is my sql script:

```
select id, number, case when numbrr < 400 then 'Yes' end result
from table
```

In real table I have a lot of data and will not work  this script
(I can't write that much data by hand)

```
case when number in (120,130) then 'Yes' end result
```

Comment: What is the problem with <?

Comment: What's wrong with `case when number < 400 then ...`? (apart form invalid column name; NUMBER is reserved for datatype name)

Comment: Put all your values in a separate table. Do a JOIN or similar.

Comment: @Jens -  I have to use it for external report, and this program where the final data comes out has a problem specifically on this "<". That's why I was interested in an alternative way.

Comment: do the opposite then `case when numbrr >= 400 then null else 'Yes' end result`. Or does it also have a problem with closing bracket '>'?

Comment: *has a problem specifically on this "<".* What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BETWEEN clause:

```
     select id, number,
            case when number between 0 and 400 
                  then 'Yes' 
            end result
       from table1;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may also use [`sign` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SIGN.html#GUID-08B75521-B5F5-4658-A005-4B4441C82945): `sign(numbrr - 400) = -1` which doesn't put any restriction on the lower boundary (which you didn't declare in the question). This function returns -1, 0 and 1 depending on the value of the expression relative to 0.

> ```
> select
>  id,
>  numbrr,
>  case
>    when sign(numbrr - 400) = -1
>    then 'Yes'
>  end as result
> from input_tab
> ```

Using this sample data

> ```
> create table input_tab (id, numbrr) as
> select 1,  450  from dual union all
> select 2,  120 from dual union all
> select 33, 130 from dual union all
> select 4,  -10 from dual
> ```

It returns

> | ID | NUMBRR | RESULT |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 450 | *null* |
> | 2 | 120 | Yes |
> | 33 | 130 | Yes |
> | 4 | -10 | Yes |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e4f82a7c27bc100dc7aab04fe45e4f7f)*